# scp command difference for Ubuntu EC2 in a VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, scp

I'm attempting to `scp` to an EC2 inside a VPC and getting timed out.

Established facts:

1. I can `ssh` into the VPC itself - the keypair works and the instance subnet is open to the internet.
2. The folder I'm attempting to transfer *to* on the EC2 has permissions `700`
3. The command I'm running is:
   `scp -i mykey.pem dumbtest.txt ubuntu@ec2-<my-ip>.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/home/ubuntu`

Are there additional steps I need to take to scp into EC2's on a VPC?

Comment: I think you would want to specify the filename in the destination: `scp -i mykey.pem dumbtest.txt ubuntu@ec2-<my-ip>.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/home/ubuntu/dumbtest.txt`

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi thanks for the proposal - that's not it though

Comment: Are you trying to copy from one EC2 to another EC2, Or from local machine to EC2

Comment: So SSH-ing into this instance works fine? Are you using SSM for ssh?

Comment: @gshpychka Yeah ssh-ing using the prompt from the EC2->Connect works, but the scp with the same key doesn't

Comment: @ShivkumarMallesappa from local to EC2

Comment: SSM instance connect is different from SSH. Try SSH from your terminal. It probably won't work.